# Keystore operation failed with RSA sign and verify

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have difficulties to use RSA for signing and verifying. Below is part of my `RSA` class that I use. The methods `init()`, `privateKey()` and `publicKey()` work fine with `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods (last two not listed here), so I assume I made some mistake inside of my `sign()` method. Method `verify()` wasn't tested yet, because signing was unsuccessful, so I wasn't able to move further. Please take a look...

---

My `RSA` class is:

```
class RSA
{
    private final static String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

    public final static int ANY_PURPOSE = KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | 
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | 
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY;

    public final static long CENTURY = (100 * 365) + 24;
```

---

```
    public enum KeySize
    {
        BIT_512  ( 512),
        BIT_768  ( 768),
        BIT_1024 (1024),
        BIT_2048 (2048),
        BIT_3072 (3072),
        BIT_4096 (4096);

        private int value;

        KeySize(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int value()
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public enum SignatureAlgorithm
    {
        MD5WithRSA        ("MD5WithRSA"),
        SHA1WithRSA       ("SHA1WithRSA"),
        SHA1WithRSA_PSS   ("SHA1WithRSA/PSS"),
        SHA224WithRSA     ("SHA224WithRSA"),
        SHA224WithRSA_PSS ("SHA224WithRSA/PSS"),
        SHA256WithRSA     ("SHA256WithRSA"),
        SHA256WithRSA_PSS ("SHA256WithRSA/PSS"),
        SHA384WithRSA     ("SHA384WithRSA"),
        SHA384WithRSA_PSS ("SHA384WithRSA/PSS"),
        SHA512WithRSA     ("SHA512WithRSA"),
        SHA512WithRSA_PSS ("SHA512WithRSA/PSS");

        private String value;

        SignatureAlgorithm(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String value()
        {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public static KeyPair init(final String alias, final RSA.KeySize keySize, 
                final long validityDays, final Boolean reset)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, 
            IOException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
        if (reset || (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)))
        {
            final long now = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator
                    .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, RSA.ANY_PURPOSE)
                    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                    .setDigests(
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE,   KeyProperties.DIGEST_MD5,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1,   KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA224,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setKeySize(keySize.value())
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE,
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1,
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                    .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal(
                            "CN=Android, O=Android Authority"))
                    .setCertificateSerialNumber(new BigInteger(256, new Random()))
                    .setCertificateNotBefore(new Date (now - (now % 1000L)))
                    .setCertificateNotAfter(new Date(((new Date(now - (now % 1000L)))
                            .getTime()) + (validityDays * 86400000L)))
                    .build());
            return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

---

```
    public static PublicKey publicKey(final String alias)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, 
            IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
        return keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
    }
```

---

```
    public static PrivateKey privateKey(final String alias)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, 
            IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
        return (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
    }
```

---

```
    public static byte[] sign(final String message, final String alias, 
                final SignatureAlgorithm algorithm)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, 
            IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
            InvalidKeyException, SignatureException
    {
        Signature instance = Signature.getInstance(algorithm.value());
        instance.initSign(privateKey(alias), new SecureRandom());
        instance.update(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return instance.sign();
    }
```

---

```
    public static Boolean verify(final String message, final byte[] signature, 
                final String alias, final SignatureAlgorithm algorithm)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, 
            IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
            InvalidKeyException, SignatureException
    {
        Signature instance = Signature.getInstance(algorithm.value());
        instance.initVerify(publicKey(alias));
        instance.update(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return instance.verify(signature);
    }
}
```

---

My `Hex` class is:

```
class Hex
{
    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToHexString(final byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] hexChars = new char[2 * bytes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        {
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[2 * i] = hexArray[b >>> 4];
            hexChars[2 * i + 1] = hexArray[b & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
}
```

---

My test code is:

```
try
{
    RSA.init("RSA", RSA.KeySize.BIT_512, RSA.CENTURY, true);

    RSA.SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = RSA.SignatureAlgorithm.SHA1WithRSA;

    byte[] x = RSA.sign("My message", "RSA", signatureAlgorithm);
    Log.d("RSA Test", "x: " + Hex.bytesToHexString(x));

    Boolean y = RSA.verify("My message", x, "RSA", signatureAlgorithm);
    Log.d("RSA Test", "y: " + (y? "True" : "False"));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d("RSA Test", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
}
```

---

And the output is:

> ERROR: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed

Debugging shows that the error occur inside of my `RSA.sign()` method, when it calls `initSign()`.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I do not see any apparent error in your code, but sometimes the initialization of the androidkeystore with too many parameters is problematic. Could you limit the initialization of your  `keyPairGenerator` to digital signature parameters?

Comment: @pedrofb - I tried, but such limitation didn't change anything.

Answer (score 10):

If you are signing with an RSA key you *must* set a signature padding mode in the [`KeyGenParameterSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setSignaturePaddings(java.lang.String...)). You haven't done so. For example, in your `init()` method you might add the following line right after `.setEncryptionPaddings()`:

```
.setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
```

e.g.

```
keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, RSA.ANY_PURPOSE)
                            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                            .setDigests(
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, KeyProperties.DIGEST_MD5,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA224,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            .setKeySize(keySize.value())
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(
                                    KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE,
                                    KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1,
                                    KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal(
                                    "CN=Android, O=Android Authority"))
                            .setCertificateSerialNumber(new BigInteger(256, new Random()))
                            .setCertificateNotBefore(new Date(now - (now % 1000L)))
                            .setCertificateNotAfter(new Date(((new Date(now - (now % 1000L)))
                                    .getTime()) + (validityDays * 86400000L)))
                            .build());
```

The other supported signature padding mode is `SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS`. Note that PSS signatures and OAEP encryption are the more modern versions of RSA block formatting for signing and encrypting. They provide better security guarantees and should always be preferred over the other modes unless they cannot be used because of interoperability issues with existing code bases.

The signature algorithm names that end in "PSS", e.g. `SHA224WithRSA_PSS` are obviously only for PSS padding, whereas the others are only for PKCS1 padding.

Comment: You are **CORRECT**, the `.setSignaturePaddings()` is the one that I didn't have and that makes a difference. Once I have added it to my code, it works! Thanks. ... I see that besides of `IGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1` there is also `SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS` option for this setting. Could you please add to your answer explanation and clarification of a difference between those two settings and if any of them is limited to set of signature algorithms defined in my class under `RSA.SignatureAlgorithm` enum. Thank you!